# There exists a homeomorphism from the whole plane to the upper half plane?

Tags: complex-analysis

There exists a homeomorphism(a continuous and bijective function whith inverse continuous) from the whole plane to the  upper half plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the *open* upper-half plane, then yes. We could take
$$
f(x,y) = (x,e^y)
$$
or, if you prefer,
$$
f(x+iy) = x + ie^y
$$

Answer (score 0):

yes 
Hint: there is a well known homeomorphism between the reals and the positive reals. you can use this on the imagimary part of the complex numbers to create a homeomorphism between the complex and upper half planes.